# Angular Life Cycle Event to check whether the DOM is fully loaded

Tags: angular

I need to use the modal footer once the template is fully loaded. If I am writing the code inside `ngAfterViewInit` then I am not getting the footer element.

If I am keeping the code inside `ngAfterViewChecked` then only I am getting the modal footer because `ngAfterViewChecked` is getting called multiple times.

This is not the correct way as sometimes any error is there then it will get logged multiple times.

What would be the appropriate method to handle this.

Comment: Can you show some code example ?

Comment: The modal footer is getting loaded from another library. I am just  trying to use that footer through javascript like: ngAfterViewInit(){const footer=document.getElementById('modalFooter');}. In this case it's not available and when I am keeping the same code inside ngAfterViewChecked then I am able to find that footer element.

Comment: for working with dom element you should use ViewChild() ([DOC](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild))